# splitting strings in oracle query

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to split my strings in Oracle based on length with space as a delimiter.

For example,

```
`MY_STRING="Before continuing, turn off the top title display without changing its definition:"`
```

My output should be

```
`STRING1="Before continuing, turn off the"`
`STRING2="top title display without changing"`
`STRING3="its definition:"`
```

The strings should be a maximum of 35 characters in length. The words after position 105 can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It colud be done with a stored function :

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_part(p_value IN VARCHAR2, part in number)
RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS temp VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    temp := p_value;
    FOR i IN 1 .. (part-1) LOOP
        if (Length(temp) <35) then
            return '';
        ELSE
            FOR j in REVERSE 1 .. 35 LOOP
                if SUBSTR(temp,j,1) = ' ' then
                    temp := SUBSTR(temp,j+1);
                    EXIT;
                end if;
            END LOOP;
            temp := SUBSTR(temp,36);
        end if;
    END LOOP;
    if (Length(temp) <=35) then
        return temp;
    else
        FOR j in reverse 1 .. 35 LOOP
            if SUBSTR(temp,j,1) = ' ' then
                return SUBSTR(temp,1,j-1);
            end if;
        END LOOP;
        return SUBSTR(temp,1,35);
    end if;

END;
```

usage:

```
select 
get_part(string_value,1), 
get_part(string_value,2), 
get_part(string_value,3) from ( select 'Before continuing, turn off the top title display without changing its definition:' string_value from dual)
```

It surely will fail if there are more than 35 chars without space, i'll leave that to you

**EDIT**: now it should split hard after 35 chars if there are no spaces

Comment: that case what should i do? if there are more than 35 chars without spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged `C#` so i chose the language to answer you. I hope it helps. It perfectly splits the text. 
Regarding the rules, in your case it splits the text in 3 parts. 
This is the Outcome :

```
STR1 :"Before continuing, turn off the"

STR2 :" top title display without changing"

STR3 :" its definition:"

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string txt = "Before continuing, turn off the top title display without changing its definition:";
    var txtArr = txt.ToCharArray();
    var counter = 0;
    var stringList = new List<string>();
    var str = string.Empty;
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.Count(); i++)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 35)
        {
            while (txtArr[i].ToString() != " ")
            {
                i--;
                str = str.Remove(i);
            }
            stringList.Add(str);
            str = string.Empty;
            counter = 0;
        }
        str = str + txtArr[i];
    }
    stringList.Add(str);
}
```

This is how I implemented the algorithm in ORACLE (PL/SQL). Ignore the error and look at the `output`. ***It returns 3 lines and works properly***. Now write some extra code and modify it as you want. The error does not seem important and I have no idea what the reason is.

```
declare 
--
txt nvarchar2(1000):='Before continuing, turn off the top title display without changing its definition:';
charc nvarchar2(1):='';
TYPE txtArrTyp IS VARRAY(1000) OF NVARCHAR2(1); 
txtArr txtArrTyp :=txtArrTyp();
--
str nvarchar2(35):='';
cntr number:=0;
j number:=0;
lent number:=0;
begin
  --
 lent:=LENGTHB(txt);
  --
for i In 1 ..lent
  loop
    if(txt is null )then
      dbms_output.put_line('SHIT');
    end if;    
    charc := SUBSTR(txt,i,1);
    txtArr.extend;
    txtArr(i):=charc;
  end loop;
  --
While(j>=1 or j<=lent)
  loop
  j:=j+1;
  cntr :=cntr+1;  
  if(cntr = 35) then
   while(txtArr(j)<>' ')
     loop
       j:=j-1;
     end loop; 
   str:=substr(str,0,j);
   dbms_output.put_line(str);
   str:=null;
   cntr:=0;  
  end if;
  str := str || txtArr(j);
  end loop; 
  dbms_output.put_line(str);
end;
```

Comment: i want it to use in a oracle selecting query, how to use it

Comment: because it's a database column(address), and i want split it in three columns.And in a oracle query also other column's are available such as name,trade,subject etc

Comment: please give me the solution for this

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT Ok I will prepar an ORA one for you.

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT Look at the update. I hope you leave a big tip!

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT I updated the solution. Run the script in pl and look at the output. Enjoy the code bro! Simply you can consider this script as a function and call it anytime you want

Comment: ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
ORA-06512: at line 40

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT I siad look at the output and ignore the error for god sake! don't you read the comments completely?!

Comment: @LEARNINGSTUDENT there are 3 different tabs at the top of pl editor for every session. one of them is the output! I ran the script and got the answer!

Comment: but when i run the script i don't got the answer.Only showing that error

Comment: please resolve this problem,any or method for do this. Because the data fetching from the oracle database table, and export in a csv file